# Функция JQuery не работает в Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть такая функция (в вёрстке без Wordpress она работала):

```
$(document).mouseover(function() {
if($('.level2:visible').length == 0)
{
    $('.nav-icon3').removeClass('open2lvl');
}
else 
{
    $('.nav-icon3').addClass('open2lvl'); 
}
```

});

я её переписала вот так:

```
jQuery(document).mouseover(function($) {
if($('.level2:visible').length == 0)
{
    $('.nav-icon3').removeClass('open2lvl');
}
else 
{
    $('.nav-icon3').addClass('open2lvl'); 
}
```

});

И теперь она не работает, хотя другие функции исправленные по этому принципу работают.
В консоли пишет, что $ не функция.
Подскажите, как написать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

нужно было везде заменить $ на jQuery

```
jQuery(document).mouseover(function() {
  if(jQuery('.level2:visible').length == 0)
  {
    jQuery('.nav-icon3').removeClass('open2lvl');
  }
  else 
  {
    jQuery('.nav-icon3').addClass('open2lvl'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что нужно было удалить $ в функции и обновить jQuery с помощью плагина jQuery Updater, вот так выглядит код, который заработал:

```
jQuery(document).mouseover(function() {
if($('.level2:visible').length == 0)
{
    $('.nav-icon3').removeClass('open2lvl');
}
else 
{
    $('.nav-icon3').addClass('open2lvl'); 
} });
```